# Odds of getting a rooster out of 5 chicks

Tags: probability

We bought 5 baby chicks who were "sexed" and are guaranteed with a 90% probability of being females.  What are our chances of having one rooster out of the 5, or worse, 2 roosters?

Answer (score 2):

The probability of five females is $\displaystyle (0.9)^5\approx 0.59$ so there's less than a 60% chance of no roosters.

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect my perspective: there is no first, 2nd, etc. , all we have is 5 indistinguishable objects, so that the only  six outcomes are : 0 male, 1 male, ...5 males , with respective probabilities $ (0.1)^5 , (0.1)^4(0.9),....$ This gives me a distribution, tho it may not be what the OP chose. Please give me some time to reply, I'm heading home; I will reply to anything else in around an hour.Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to think and correct but I had two security guards shouting at me to get of the library and I could not think clearly; I was trying to do something somewhat-fancy, but I lost track of it so I'm deleting.